# Python hex string encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

I'm trying to convert a bytearray to and from a string. Why does the following not work? The encode seems to add an extra slash. Am I using the wrong encoding? I'm using python3.6

```
In [19]: b'\x88'.decode('unicode_escape')
Out[19]: '\x88'

In [20]:  '\x88'.encode('unicode_escape')
Out[20]: b'\\x88'
```

Answer (score 2):

**When to use raw_unicode_escape mode**

The backslash character is escaped so is written as \\. If you don't want that try the 'raw_unicode_escape' codec.

In the editor here, when answering your question, if I write \\ you see \ in the response so I actually had to write \\\\. Try it yourself to see what I mean (or edit this answer to see what I mean).

This is what I actually had to write above

```
The backslash character is escaped so is written as \\\\.
If you don't want that try the 'raw_unicode_escape' codec.

In the editor here, when answering your question, if I write \\\\
you see \\ in the response so I actually had to write 
\\\\\\\\. Try it yourself to see what I mean (or edit this answer 
to see what I mean).
```

By escaping the backspash the unicode_escape codec guards against problems like that.

Answer (score 0):

You are using here `bytes` not `bytearray`
So, if you want to encode and decode keeping the '\x', you can use

```
'\x88'.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
b'\x88'.decode('unicode_escape')
```

If what you have is a single value `bytearray` like this:

```
barray = bytearray([0x88])
```

you can get the string of this byte this way:

```
s = format(barray[0], '02x')
```